# Table padding not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been struggling with this table for the past few days and finally got it how I want it only to discover that the text alignment is not working correctly in chrome. It displays exactly how I want it in ie and firefox (vertically aligned to the middle and padded left) However it isn't coming through in chrome. Any help would be amazing, I'm at my whits end.

Opening up these two in jfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kaRev/). The next image illustrates the problem I am having between the two browsers (chrome and ff). Firefox on the right pads it correctly, while chrome on the left does not

[image]

Here is a screen shot of chrome where the text in the table is too far left.

[image]

And here is firefox which is how I want it:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="tableBenefits">
<thead>
<tr>
          <th style="height:34px;width: 207px;font-weight:bold;color:#D2161C;" class="headneed">
      &nbsp Your Need        </th>
          <th style="height:34px;width: 166px;font-weight:bold;color:#D2161C;" class="headfeature">
      Feature        </th>
          <th style="height:34px;width: 260px;font-weight:bold;color:#D2161C;" class="headbenefits">
      Benefits   </th>

      </tr>
</thead>

<tbody >
      <tr class="row-mid">
              <td class="need">
        Notify technicians &amp; managers of work order status updates          </td>
              <td class="feature">
        Automated work order email notifications          </td>
              <td class="benefits">
        Keeps team updated on work order status; reduces admin time on work orders          </td>



          </tr>

  <tr class="row-mid">
              <td class="need">
        Notify service/repair requesters of progress          </td>
              <td class="feature">
        Automated service request email notifications          </td>
              <td class="benefits">
        Keeps requesters updated on progress; reduces personnel time for providing updates          </td>
          </tr>

  <tr class="row-mid">
              <td class="need">
        Manage &amp; track work orders          </td>
              <td class="feature">
        Work Order Forms, Linking, &amp; Routing          </td>
              <td class="benefits">
        Simplifies work order administration &amp; reduces data entry time          </td>
          </tr>

  <tr class="row-mid">
              <td class="need">
        Manage service &amp; repair requests          </td>
              <td class="feature">
        Web-based Service Request Form          </td>
              <td class="benefits">
        Simplifies request submission and routing          </td>
          </tr>
  </tbody>
```

CSS:

```
.tableBenefits thead {
background: url(http://www.mpulsesoftware.com/sites/all/themes/zen/image/top_eq.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.tableBenefits {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

.tableBeneits thead th {
font-weight:bold;color:#D2161C;
}

.tableBenefits {height:300px;width:640px;}

.headneed{font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;}
.headfeature{font-size:11px;}
.headbenefits{font-size:11px;}
.need{font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;}
.feature{font-size:11px;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;}
.benefits{font-size:11px;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;}
.row-mid{background: url("http://www.mpulsesoftware.com/sites/all/themes/zen/image/middle_eq.jpg")repeat-y;width:640px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

.row-last{background: url("http://www.mpulsesoftware.com/sites/all/themes/zen/image/bottom_eq.jpg")repeat-y;width:640px;}



/* Webtk hack*/

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {




.tableBenefits td, .tableBenefits th {
  display: inline-table;

}

.headneed, .need{
  width: 207px;


}
.headfeature, .feature{
  width: 166px;

 }

.headbenefits, .benefits{
  width: 260px;

 }

}

/* End benefits table */
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this `display: inline-table;`

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks the background in the table heading. Is there a way to work with it? A float or something? Or another work around for the table heading background.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing. It looks exactly like in firefox without the inline-table. Both the table header and columns.

Comment: Weird, for me the thead bg starts repeating

Comment: However,
In case anyone is wondering using `display: inline-block;`
instead of`display: inline-block;` worked perfectly after adjusting the spacing a little

Comment: You might want to re-read your last comment. I have no idea what it's supposed to say.